# Changing text in file that generates HREF attribute in HTML with PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, fopen, fwrite

I need to be able to change text in a text file that is used to generate an HREF attribute of a link in my page through a form (i.e. the user puts the link into form and the link in HTML will change). So far I made that form and one PHP script. It is working, except that it won't just change that HREF attribute but it's making a whole new link (i.e. `<a href="Link"><img src="web/assets/images/youtube.png" alt="YT" width="42" height="42" border="0"></a>`) in the HTML.

Its working like that - when you put link into form, that script will write that link into the TXT file, then on that page where I need to have that HREF is another script that takes out link from a text file. Here is the PHP:

```
<?php
$subor = @file('youtube.txt');
$lines = sizeof($subor);
$count = $lines/1;
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
{
?> 
<a href="<?php echo ($subor[$i * 1 + 0]) ?>"><img 
src="web/assets/images/youtube.png" alt="YT" width="42" height="42" 
border="0"></a>
<?php   
}
?>
```

And this is script that is writing the link from form into the text file:

```
<?php
$myFile = "youtube.txt";
if(isset($_POST['flag']) && !empty($_POST['flag'])) {
    $fileWrite = $_POST['flag'] . "\n";
}
if($fileWrite) {
    $fh = fopen($myFile, "a") or die("can't open file"); //Make sure you have permission
    fwrite($fh, $fileWrite);
    fclose($fh);
    exec('/your/command /dev/null 2>/dev/null &');
}
?>
<?php
header( 'Location: http://kraj.com/home.php' ) ;
?>
```

So how to edit that code so it won't create another  but it will change the href inside that one  ?

Comment: That first script is inside index.php page

Comment: `$count = $lines/1;` WHY????

Comment: `$subor[$i * 1 + 0]` Why why ????

Comment: oh that´s a mistake

Comment: And some muppet upvotes this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Mode parameter

> So how to edit that code so it wont create another but it will change href inside that one ?

Change the second parameter (i.e. ***mode***) passed to [fopen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) to `'w'`. That way the pointer will be placed at the beginning of the file, instead of having the pointer at the end of the file (for appending).

```
 $fh = fopen($myFile, "w") or die("can't open file"); //Make sure you have permission
```

See a demonstration of this in [this playground example](https://www.tehplayground.com/qrzr8bBV7fMeY7bp).

#### File_put_contents()

A simpler technique would be to use [file_put_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php). Then the following three lines

```
$fh = fopen($myFile, "a") or die("can't open file"); //Make sure you have permission
fwrite($fh, $fileWrite);
fclose($fh);
```

could be replaced with:

```
$numberOfBytesWritten = file_put_contents($myFile, $fileWrite);
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! Works perfect!